Morphic Composition in Localization Categories
In the category localization discussed in the Stacks Project, there is a description in the morphism composition of localized categories as follows: The composition of the equivalence classes of the pairs $(f: X \rightarrow Y^{'}, s: Y \rightarrow Y^{'})$ and $(g: Y \rightarrow Z^{'}, t: Z \rightarrow Z^{'})$ is defined as the equivalence class of a pair $(h \circ f: X \rightarrow Z^{''}, u \circ t: Z \rightarrow Z^{''})$ where $h$ and $u \in S$ are chosen to fit into a commutative diagram which exists by assumption. 
My question is, does this mean $h, u \in S$ or just $u \in S$? If it is the former meaning, how to prove the existence of such a commutative graph. It seems that LMS2 can only prove the existence of a commutative graph with the latter meaning

Just $u \in S$.
